# Is there a way to assert that response body has required parameters in Json through RestAssured Java

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

I need to assert in rest-assured Jave that the response body of Json has required parameters.
How can I do that instead of just coverting Json as string and then asserting if string contains a text, as that text can be in vaule of a parameter as well?

Here is that sample Json:

```
[
    {
        "modificationDate": "2018-12-10T09:39:07Z",
        "startDate": "2018-11-08T04:59:25Z",
        "endDate": "2018-12-10T09:39:07Z"

    },

    {
        "modificationDate": "2008-12-10T09:39:07Z",
        "startDate": "2008-11-08T04:59:25Z",
        "endDate": "2008-12-10T09:39:07Z"

    }
]
```

So How can I assert that `modificationDate`, `startDate` and `endDate` parameters are found in response body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Hamcrest.hasKey(K key)`](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/javadoc/1.3/org/hamcrest/Matchers.html#hasKey%28K%29) to test existence of key in the body.

```
when().get("....")
    .then().body("$", hasKey("modificationDate"))
           .body("$", hasKey("startDate"))
           .body("$", hasKey("endDate"))
```

Considering you are getting something like this

```
{
    "modificationDate": "...",
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": ""
}
```

Comment: @Waqas, If this answer helps and works for you, please mark it as answer.

Comment: I have tried this, but I am getting "Cannot Resolve Symbol Matchers" at import static org.hamcrest.Matchers; Even when I have added following in POM:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hamcrest-junit</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>